# XSD cant create class from XML based on inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I got problem with creating *.cs (C# Class) based on XML generated by serializing another C# class. XSD.exe throws following error:

```
- A column named 'Conditions' already belongs to this DataTable: cannot set a
  nested table name to the same name.
```

My process looks like this:

1. Writing some C# code (example below)
2. Serialize to XML  use XSD.EXE to
3. create *.cs Deserialize to new *.cs
4. (for shipping) etc

The classes which are serialized to XML (in point 1) looks like this:

```
public class A
{
   public A(){}
   private List<string> _cond = new List<String>();
   public List<string> Conditions 
   {
      get{ return _cond; }
      set{ _cond = value }
   }
}

public class B:A
{
}
public class C:A
{
}

public class Data
{
  B b = new B();
  C c = new C();
  /* ... ADD SOME DATA etc ... */
} 

// After that I serialize to XML the "Data" class object
```

Can anyone suggest of workaround ?! This is clearly cause by inherided condition property

Comment: "useless forums... – condproblem" What should we make out of that comment? That kinda explains why nobody else answered before me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way xsd.exe creates the output, n your case, it would make sense to use the /c(lasses) switch. Then, it will not create a dataset but "ordinary" classes instead.

There's also [LinqToXsd](http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/), which has a fairly decent code generator.